# Discord.js V12 find a role that starts with something

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How could I make it so it finds a role that starts with for example `Leader` and it will find a role `Leader of server` for example... Please let me know :D
current code:

```
        const leaderRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Leader");
        const leaderMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.roles.cache.find(role => role == leaderRole)).map(member => member.user);
```

Comment: Also if it could find the role that can be uppercased or lowecased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
role.name.indexOf('Leader') !== -1
```

For case sensitivity.

```
role.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('leader')
```

e.g.

```
const leaderRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name.indexOf('Leader') !==-1 );
```